# What is the longest word in type $C_2$ Weyl group written in terms of a matrix?

Tags: algebraic-groups, weyl-group

The longest word in type $A_3$ Weyl group written as a matrix is 
\begin{align}
w_0=s_1s_2s_1=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).
\end{align}

What is the longest word in type $C_2$ Weyl group written in terms of a matrix? In this case, $w_0 = s_1 s_2 s_1 s_2$. How to write $s_1, s_2$ as matrices? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean "what is the matrix, in terms of a basis of simple roots, of the transformation of the root system induced by …"?  In this case, the matrices of simple reflections very nearly come from the Cartan matrix.  Although you must usually specify your numbering of simple roots, of course here it doesn't matter.  If $\alpha_1$ is the short root and $\alpha_2$ the long, then $s_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $s_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: It's scalar multiplication by $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

To answer these questions we have great computer algebra systems such as [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)

```
W = WeylGroup("C2")
W.long_element()
```

You can run short snippets of code like these on [SageCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwLV7BVCE-tzHEvyi8t0FByNlLS5OUK18vJz0uPT81JzU3NK9HQBADSrAtz&lang=sage)

Answer (score 0):

The Chevalley basis of $sp_4$ is generated by 
\begin{align}
& e_1=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \end{array}\right), \ e_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right), \\ &  f_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right), f_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).
\end{align}
We have 
\begin{align}
\overline{s}_i = \exp(-e_i)\exp(f_i)\exp(-e_i).
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
& \overline{s}_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \end{array}\right), \quad \overline{s}_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right), \\
& \overline{s}_1 \overline{s_2} \overline{s}_1 \overline{s}_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right), \quad s_1 s_2 s_1 s_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).
\end{align}